# Corba remote access

Tags: java, corba, idl

I have a Corba server runnning in a system, which I want to access from another machine on the same LAN. I tried giving the server ip of the server machine to access (code attached); however I get the error mentioned below:

```
orbd -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost <serverip>&

java HelloServer -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost <serverip>&

java HelloClient -ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost <serverip>&

WARNING: "IOP00410201: (COMM_FAILURE) Connection failure: socketType: IIOP_CLEAR_TEXT; hostname: 127.0.1.1; port: 43944"
org.omg.CORBA.COMM_FAILURE:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 201  completed: No
```

- It says host name as 127.0.1.1, but that is not the server name i specified.
- The portnumber  is different form wat i have specified
- The server has not recieved any connections and is still waiting.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Which of the apps above throws the exception? client or server?

Comment: Can you show us the code of `HelloClient` and `HelloServer`?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Thanks ppl. I have changed /etc/hosts conf file. Changed the localhost ip, and how I am able to access remote server.

Answer (score 1):

CORBA programs do not deal directly with IP addresses of the server. When you want to access some object you need its IOR - or interchangeable object reference. IOR contains address of the machine that needs to be contacted about the object, some object ID, and some more administrativia.

There are 2 most common ways to get IOR of some object. Low level approach is that server converts to string, and write that string into some file. Client reads that string and converts it to object reference.

Other approach is to have name service running which is responsible for converting names to IORs. Something like DNS for objects.

Typical CORBA program would go through this dance only for one or few "root" objects, and object references for other objects get returned as return values from calls to that root objects.

Comment: This is all true, but i don't think it's relevant. The addresses and ports are being supplied to the programs so that they can connect to the ORB. That is necessary so the programs can connect to the naming service and so on, from which they can then retrieve objects identified by IORs, as you describe. So, the programs really do need the address and port of the ORB server.

Comment: Unless they are not connecting to the Naming service but directly to the strignified IOR, or program expects an stringfied IOR of the naming service and not IP of it. I would assume that for very simple hello world naming service is not at all involved but stringfied IORs

Comment: The example above uses java´s build in naming service provided by the daemonized ordb process

Comment: The server's IP address and port actually go into the IOR, so yes, they are needed. Typically you specify what IP address and port number you want a server to advertise in its IOR as command line arguments to the server application.

Answer (score -1):

in the argument side  of code for each server and client you need to

```
-ORBInitialPort 1050 -ORBInitialHost serverIP
```